# Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac 17.3.1 current column number

Tags: visual-studio-mac

Is there a way to show current column number of the cursor in code editor?

[image: VS IDE Screenshot]

Comment: @JamesRisner Current column number of the cursor

Comment: Seems like the ruler might be related but not quite what you are looking for: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/source-editor?view=vsmac-2022#ruler

Comment: @cr1pto Nope, I need exact column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac 17.4 preview 2 now has the line number, column number, and line ending information at the bottom right hand corner of the text editor.

[image: Visual Studio for Mac 17.4 - line/column number UI]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to show current column number of the cursor in code
> editor?

Your photo indicates you are using Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

VSC is more text editor oriented while VS is more IDE based.

VS only supports showing the line and column number of the cursor location in the [Windows version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-the-status-bar?view=vs-2022) of VS2022 at this time.

The column numbers are a feature of [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=darwin-universal) in the 1.70.2 universal version I used.[image: vsc]